# how to make Toolbar in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, iboutlet

I want to make `UIToolbar` in interface builder but when drag `UIToolbar` in my xib file and connect to MyTool `IBOutlet` when run this app don't display to me...

where are my mistake!!! please guide me how to make UIToolbar in my app with IBOutlet (interface builder)!!!

thanks.

Comment: Are you running on an iPhone 4 screen when this happens by any chance?

Comment: give more information add screenshots

Comment: Did you set the constraints for your tool bar?

Comment: @rdelmar how to set constraints for toolbar?

Comment: The same way you do with anything else. Go to the "pin" icon at the bottom of the canvas and pin it to the sides and top (or bottom wherever you want it), and also height. Then click the button at the bottom that will say "add 4 constraints"